# PlayerPrefs working on unity editor but not in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've looking for info to try to solve my problem and I just can't figure out what it's causing it. Player Prefs seem to work fine in unity editor, but once i make a build for Android or PC they are all gone. I have PlayerPrefs.deleteAll no where in my project.

I have 3 scenes: Menu, Game and GameOver. When I start the Menu scene, I run this script attached to the MainCamera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class prefs : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int bestRecord;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bestRecord = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("K", 1);
        Debug.Log(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("K").ToString());
    }

}
```

When I go into the Game scene, my score is a TextMeshProUGUI that is constantly update by an InvokeRepeating:

```
    public TextMeshProUGUI points;

     void Start()
    {
        stop = false;
        InvokeRepeating("subirMetros", 0f, 0.01f);
    }

    private void subirMetros()
    {
        if (stop == false)
        {
            points.SetText(Math.Round(character.transform.position.x, 0) + "");
        }
    }

    //GameOver is called when the player dies
    public void GameOver()
    {
        stop = true;
        CancelInvoke("subirMetros");
        int finalPoints = Int32.Parse(points.text);
        int recordActual = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("K");
        if (recordActual < finalPoints)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("K", finalPoints);
        }
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");
    }
}
```

Finally, when starting the GameOver scene, I get once again the PlayerPrefs that are supposedly saved before I get to the scene:

```
public TextMeshProUGUI record;
void Start()
{
    record.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("K").ToString();
}
```

The weird thing is that this is working in the unity editor, but not when i build it. I would be very grateful if someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: For debugging purposes, to mirror what a new user of your app would see, it's good practice to occassionally use `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll()` when running from editor. (Wrap it with #if UNITY_EDITOR for extra safety in case you forget to take it out.) After doing so, hit play again in Editor -- is everything working as expected?

Comment: Why don't you call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` at all?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen I did'nt know this feature, I've been testing and I'm still getting 0 score when building... It has no sense because I'm using 1 as default value. It stills work in the editor when I delete all Player Prefs.

Comment: @trojanfoe I was saving them OnApplicationQuit(), just tried to save them after setting the new value and it does not work on build

Comment: You need to debug as already suggested.  However you should store data using the most appropriate data type, which is `int`, so use that internally instead of `string`.  It might be that the `string` is not in the format you expect and therefore is failing to convert to `int`.

Comment: @trojanfoe That was it! It was an error in the conversion... Thanks a lot!

Comment: ... so you are now using an `int` right?

Comment: Now I use a double to store the score and I parse it to Float. Now my PlayerPref is a Float. The problem was that Math.Round returns a double not an int. That was giving me problems when casting

Comment: Well that is better than string, provided the value being stored is a real number and not an integer.

Comment: Int32.Tryparse is your friend

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post (forgive me for necro) but it came up as a google search result, and i ran into the same issue.

I had the same issue with playerprefs, i was saving an encrypted file where i used a playerprefs together with a generated key for a hash value. When i saved the game in the editor and ran in the build i couldnt load my save file. This was for windows though. After some debugging and digging I found out that unity saves playerprefs two different places for both editor and application builds:

according to this article
https://virtual-reality-piano.medium.com/solved-where-is-unitys-playerprefs-stored-on-windows-d61d504585e9

Your unity editor saves it at the path:  ‘HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Unity\UnityEditor\CompanyName\ProjectName’

But, when you build your application, the player prefs are saved at:

'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\CompanyName\ProjectName'  (where Company name is the name of your company, and project name is the name of your project).

I had to go in and delete the registry files in both places, because say i was saving a Save File with the name DefaultPlayer, then the editor would associate that save with the registry file from the editor. But when i build to an application, the save file would still persist in Application.PersistentPath, but it's registry file would not exist, because it wasn't created yet in the application's registry file.

Sorry for the confusing post and necro, but this is what fixed save file problems for me from editor to application builds. (note this is on windows so dont know if it applies to android as well). Hope it helps anyone else running into the same problem

note you would have to delete both files everytime you test in editor and on builds, or as someone suggested in a comment above, use the #if UNITY_EDITOR pragma to avoid the error

Answer (score 0):

I read your post and I have a similar problem with this.
Before I have built an apk file but it was not working on the emulator.
But it was working on Unity Editor well.
I couldn't find the reason for this problem but I think there is a problem when the scene is loading using SceneManager.LoadScene().
When I don't use this function, the error was fixed.
If you fix this problem, please post how did you do.
And I think it is better to avoid errors than fixing errors.
Good luck.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).